# How do I dictate what DocType is used by SSRS URL Access?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, doctype

I have an Asp.Net Webform app that I specify the following `DOCTYPE` in the Master File.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

However, on my Reports page I have URL Access links to reports on Reporting Services that open in a new browser tab.  These keep opening in IE5 Mode which totally ruins the Toolbar display.  I can't seem to figure out how you can change the Document Mode for a page returned by SSRS.

Comment: I think most SSRS pages can be edited if you find the right file in your installation folder.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...I should look on the Report Server for an instance of that Report?  No?